Restore snapshot of AWS Lightsail cPanel/WHM instance
I need to restore a backup of a cPanel/WHM instance in AWS Lightsail. However, once I attach the static IP to the new instance, my sites no longer load and I get the following error message.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the DNS or IP.
Is there a shell script I need to run on the new instance after I've attached the static IP?
